# SSRS filter date time not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Report SSRS in window 10 and open from IE 11 
my computer  filter date  not working (not show image calendars)
How to fixed .
thank you.

[image: enter image description]

Comment: How are you getting the dates? From the looks of it you are missing a 0 in the time part of the dates.

Comment: The error is showing you that the dates must be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. The `Start Date` looks like it's `DD/MM/YYYY` format. Change the parameters to `Date/Time`.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on WEI_DBA, it looks like you need to set the default value of your Start Date parameter to `="3/16/2017 0:00:00"` since your date format has months and days reversed.

Note that this can be confusing when you have a server with a different region setting than your workstation.  The report is fine to develop locally and will then generate this error when deployed to your server.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter pane, right-click on Start Date and select Parameter Properties.  Find "Data Type:" in the middle of the dialog and change the drop down to be Date/Time.  Do the same for End date.

A date/time parameter will will show the date picker and will ensure you are passing a properly structured date value into your dataset query, regardless of your culture/language settings.